# Specify absolute address on embedded 32bit

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to develop a memory area written in C on a 32bit embedded device where data is to be stored on specific addresses.

I currently have the memory area in a section, let say between 0x1000-0x2000 but I need to specify the data in specific addresses.

```
uint8_t data[0x100]; /* This should be stored at eg. 0x1020 */
uint8_t data2[0x100]; /* This should be stored at eg. 0x1500 */
uint8_t data3[0x100]; /* This should be stored at 0x1F00 */
```

The solution I came up with is to create reserved blocks in between the data blocks.

```
typedef struct data_t
{
 uint8_t reserved1[0x1020]; /* Used for padding */
 uint8_t data[0x100]; /* This should be stored at eg. 0x1020 */
 uint8_t reserved2[0x3E0]; /* Used for padding */
 uint8_t data2[0x100]; /* This should be stored at eg. 0x1500 */
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is a nicer solution then that or a smarter solution. I'm using GHS compiler for the ones with GCC tricks.

Comment: if you use GHS you have a paid support.

Answer (score 2):

use linker script for that. Place section at the address, then place variables in this section.

Another way:

```
typedef struct
{
 uint8_t reserved1[0x1020]; /* Used for padding */
 uint8_t data[0x100]; /* This should be stored at eg. 0x1020 */
 uint8_t reserved2[0x3E0]; /* Used for padding */
 uint8_t data2[0x100]; /* This should be stored at eg. 0x1500 */
}data_t;

#define DATA1 ((volatile data_t *)0x1020)

//usage
void foo()
{
    DATA1 -> data[5] = 4;
}
```

Comment: Can a linker script specific multiple arrays on different specified locations?
I have a memory section where everything is stored, but I need to specify exactly. But I see your other example. I would like to avoid using reserved areas, but I think its the only option.

Comment: @dislo Yes. You have the option to either declare an arbitrary number of memory regions in the linker script and then to allocate structs at the same location (like this), or better to just declare your symbols in C code, and to use the resulting identifiers in the linker script. Either way, there is no practical limit for the number of targeted placements.